# Not able to run BHO when IE is opened as non admin in EPM mode

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, bho

I have made a simple BHO using C# as per the below link : 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19971/How-to-attach-to-Browser-Helper-Object-BHO-with-C

BHO gets loaded when I open IE as Administrator(by right click on it and click Run as admin)

But same BHO is not getting loaded by IE when I open it in non admin mode.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create and deploy both a x86 and x64 versions of your BHO if it is for public web sites, otherwise EPM is disabled by default for the IE Intranet zone.

Compare your IE Security zone settings on the Admin and user accounts.... you should be accepting the defaults set by your system administrators.